# WebApplication in amazon

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Myself trying to host a simple web application in amazon.My application takes data from  mysql database.which option i willl select from amazon amazon static webpage hosting or amazon ec2?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

All dependes on your web application load... you can start with an EC2 micro-instance, an 30GB EBS with mysql+apache installed and an Elastc IP, all this will be under free tier, so you can taste aws server and measure your real needs.

By the way, there is a lot of things which you can go under free tier, take a look: http://aws.amazon.com/pt/free/

Comment: Think of S3 as a USB Flash Drive. A really, really big Flash drive. It can't process anything — it's just storage. EC2 on the other hand is a full virtual machine with a CPU and everything. EC2 is the right answer.